# How to call MapStruct method from interface in java stream

Tags: java, stream, dto, mapstruct

I recently started using the MapStruct mapping tool in a project. In the past, for mapping DTO -> Entity and vice versa I used custom mapper like:

```
public static CustomerDto toDto(Customer customer) {

    return isNull(customer)
        ? null
        : CustomerDto.builder()
            .id(customer.getId())
            .name(customer.getName())
            .surname(customer.getSurname())
            .phoneNumber(customer.getPhoneNumber())
            .email(customer.getEmail())
            .customerStatus(customer.getCustomerStatus())
            .username(customer.getUsername())
            .NIP(customer.getNIP())
            .build();
  }
```

In case when I was trying to get one single Optional object after all I was able to map my entity to dto in the following way:

```
public Optional<CustomerDto> findOneById(final long id) {
    return customerRepository.findById(id).map(CustomerMapper::toDto);
  }
```

Currently, as I mentioned before I am using mapStruct and the problem is that my mapper it's, not class, it's the interface like:

```
@Mapper
public interface CommentMapper {

  @Mappings({
      @Mapping(target = "content", source = "entity.content"),
      @Mapping(target = "user", source = "entity.user")
  })
  CommentDto commentToCommentDto(Comment entity);

  @Mappings({
      @Mapping(target = "content", source = "dto.content"),
      @Mapping(target = "user", source = "dto.user")
  })
  Comment commentDtoToComment(CommentDto dto);

}
```

I want to know if it possible to use somehow this interface method in stream gentle to map my value without wrapping values like:

```
public Optional<CommentDto> findCommentById(final long id) {

    Optional<Comment> commentById = commentRepository.findById(id);
    return Optional.ofNullable(commentMapper.commentToCommentDto(commentById.get()));
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Optional = A container object which may or may not contain a non-null value. Please don't return it as a result of a method "findById" if there is no comment just return null! 
Comment comment = commentRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);

Comment: MapStructs is like lombok a pre processed interface which is generating an Impl class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access the mapper like:

```
private static final YourMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper(YourMapper.class);

final Optional<YourEntity> optEntity = entityRepo.findById(id);
return optEntity.map(MAPPER::toDto).orElse(null);
```

Basically we do a similar thing with enumerations

```
 @Mapping(target = "type", expression = "java(EnumerationType.valueOf(entity.getType()))")
```

you can define java expressions in your @Mapping annotation

```
@Mapping(target = "comment", expression = "java(commentMapper.commentToCommentDto(commentRepository.findById(entity.commentId).orElse(null)))"
```

Otherwise you should be able to make use of a

```
class CommentMapper { ... }
```

which you automatically can refer with

```
@Mapper(uses = {CommentMapper.class})
```

your implementation will detect the commentEntity and Dto and will automatically use the CommentMapper.

A MapStruct mapper is workling like: Shit in Shit out, so remember your entity needs the commentEntity so the dto can has the commentDto.

**EDIT**

2nd solution could be using:

```
@BeforeMapping
default void beforeMappingToDTO(Entity source, @MappingTarget Dto target) {
    target.setComment(commentMapper.commentToCommentDto(commentRepository.findById(entity.commentId).orElse(null)));
}
```

Comment: 5 minutes ago I find out the solution. Anyway, thank you so much for a fast response.

Comment: @Martin did you use the above answer? Can you indicate which solution? Please mark it as answered then. @Spektakulatius, I prefer your seconds solution, but I guess you need to hand down the `commentRepository` in you second solution as `@Context`. Look at https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/blob/master/mapstruct-jpa-child-parent/src/main/java/org/mapstruct/jpa/SourceTargetMapper.java for an example

Comment: @Sjaak yes, I used the first one. The second solution would be great if we would map the entire collection with annotation usage. 
For my particular problem I used the first one like:

`return commentRepository.findById(id).map(CommentMapper.MAPPER::commentToCommentDto);`

Comment: @Sjaak answer for a question added. Thanks for commitment.

Comment: Thanks for 2nd solution. I wanted to set a default value to target so badly and couldn't find how. `@BeforeMapping` did the job

Answer (score 2):

@Spektakulatius answer solved a problem.

To reach a goal I made a few steps:
First of all, I created an object of my mapper to use it in a java stream:

```
private CommentMapper commentMapper = Mappers.getMapper(CommentMapper.class);
```

In the last step I used my object commentMapper like:

```
public Optional<CommentDto> findCommentById(final long id) {
    return commentRepository.findById(id).map(CommentMapper.MAPPER::commentToCommentDto);
}
```

After all that completely gave me a possibility to use my custom MapStruct mapper in stream.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to extend functional interface in mapper like this:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper extends Function<MySource, MyTarget> {
}
```

In this case mapstruct will implement method apply from Function. When you do it like this you can simply just use instance of mapper as parameter of map function. In spring you can even inject your mapper using Function type like this:

```
class MyService {
    private final Function<MySource, MyTarget> mapper;
    private final MyRepo repository;
    
    // required arg constructor here

    public Optional<MyTarget> findById(final long id) {
       return repository.findById(id).map(mapper);
    }
}
```

I think this is really elegant way how you can do it. I am using that approach also in other cases. For mapping to existing source you can use BiFunction functional interface. Maybe cosmetic downside of this approach is you have to have separate mapper interface for every mapping method you would like to use in functional way.